# Meaning of "to + have +to "

Tags: modal-verbs

I am confused with the following sentences -

> The players are keen not to have to think about the
>   situation while the current series with Pakistan is
>   going on.

I am, actually, confused with the part "keen not to have to " what is the meaning of "have" here? Please explain this sentence to me.

Comment: **Have** is used here in the sense of _obligation._ Did you consult your dictionary to learn about the verb [**have?**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have?s=t) It has dozens of meanings and uses.

Comment: This is actually two separate phrases that look like one.  It's not **"to have to"**, it's **"keen (not) to"** and **"have to"**.  You could say "they are keen (not) to sleep/eat spaghetti/visit Paris/(any verb at all)" but the phrase in question just happens to be "have to", and the thing that they have to do is "think about the situation".  If you look up the meanings of these phrases separately, the meaning of the whole sentence should become clearer.

Answer (score 1):

'They have to do this' here means they need to do something. Your sentence means that the players will be happy if they do not need to think about the situation.